# Short texture in webGL

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, textures, webgl

I have a `short` texture that I want to read from in a shader, webgl does not support `short` textures so I split the short in to two bytes and send it to the shader:

```
var ushortValue = reinterval(i16Value, -32768, 32767, 0, 65535);

textureData[j*4] = ushortValue & 0xFF; // first byte
ushortValue = ushortValue >> 8;
textureData[j*4+1] = ushortValue & 0xFF; // second byte
textureData[j*4+2] = 0;
textureData[j*4+3] = 0;
```

And then I upload the data to the graphic card:

```
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, width, height, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureData);
```

In fragment shader:

```
vec4 valueInRGBA = texture2D(ctTexture, xy)*255.0; // range 0-1 to 0-255
float real_value = valueInRGBA.r + valueInRGBA.g*256;
real_value  = reinterval(real_value , 0.0, 65535.0,  0.0, 1.0);
gl_FragColor = vec4(real_value, real_value, real_value, 1.0);
```

But I am lost resolution compared to when I upload the short data in normal opengl that has support for short textures. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

[image]

Here is another strange different I get between webgl and opengl, with the same data. I a draw the value as above I get the same colors but I little less resolution. And then I add two lines:

```
ct_value = reinterval(ct_value, 0.0, 65535.0,  -32768.0, 32767.0);
ct_value = reintervalClamped(ct_value, -275.0, 475.0, 0.0, 1.0);
gl_FragColor = vec4(ct_value,ct_value,ct_value,1.0);
```

In opengl everything looks good but in webgl everything turns white with the exact the same code.

Opengl: [image]
Webgl: [image]

Comment: shouldn't you multiply in the shader by 255.0 (2^8-1) instead of 254.0?

Comment: or even *256*, because `ushortValue = ushortValue >> 8;` is dividing by the

Comment: I changed it, thank you, but still, the resolution is still bad

Comment: Can you add an image?

Comment: I cant show you the whole image because its real ct data from a patient, but you can see the bad resolution in this one.

Comment: and if you change linear to nearest neighbour?

Comment: What float precision did you set in your fragment shader? You would need `highp`.

Comment: yes I am using highp, but its still 16 bits instead of 32 in webgl is not? maybe this is the quality lost I see?

Comment: You're rendering 16bit data, what exactly are you expecting the result to be? The output to your screen will still be 32bit so 8bit for each channel. Btw. you could pack your texture more tightly by using `RGBA_4_4_4_4` which essentially is a `SHORT` texture.

Comment: Well, splitting a value over several texture channels will only work if no interpolation is used, as you won't get correct wrapover behavior between the channels. Splitting the data over 4 channels instead of two will make problems wore.

Comment: Sure it will, but i think the OPs problem about "resolution" is based on the fact that he's rendering 16bit data into 8bit channels, thus not seeing a difference between 8bit and 16bit approach. In the code currently given there is nothing done besides outputting the data, which could be done by just compressing the 16bit data into a 8bit luminance texture, no need to have the 16bit data available on the gpu. But maybe *i just dont get it*.

Comment: @LJ_1102 Yes, it's pointless if you end up mapping the whole range to the final output. But with medical imaging, it's common for the original data to have more than 8 bits of precision, and to use an adjustable offset/scale (or a more general transfer function) to map the data to the final color. This is not shown in the posted code, but I figure it must be simplified.

Comment: @derhass Based on scribbling it down, doing linear interpolation should actually be fine. Doing linear interpolation of each component separately, and then combining them, is the same as doing linear interpolation on the combined components. At least based on my math, I believe it works in this case since the components are linearly combined to obtain the final value. With `a_i` the weights and `h_i`/`l_i` the high/low bytes, `sum(a_i * (256 * h_i + l_i))` is the same as `256 * sum(a_i * h_i) + sum(a_i * l_i)`.

Comment: I added one more question above

Comment: @RetoKoradi You miss the wraparound and the "carry" behavior. Assume we have an `uint16` as two 8bit channels. In the worst case, we have 0xff right next to 0x100 and are sampling exactly at the border between those. Interpolation will get us with 0 or 1 for the high byte, and 0x7f or 0x80 for the low byte, so we can be up to 0x80 off here. Things get worse when we split this into 4 channels, as now, we might be up to 0x800 off.

Answer (score 0):

I am solving same problem and it works fine for me. My implementation is in dart, but it is similar.
I have 2 possible solutions:

1) Use float texture

```
gl.getExtension("OES_texture_float")
texture format = GL.LUMINANCE
texture data type = GL.FLOAT

maxValue = (signed)?32767.0:65535.0;
textureData = new Float32List(width*height);
for (int i=0;i<size;i++) {
  textureData[i] = data[i]/maxValue;
}
```

This solution works great and there is no need to perform any special calculations in shader, but you need OES_float_linear extension to use linear texture interpolation and current version of Chrome does not support it.

2) Use your solution with storing short value to RGB

```
pixels = new Uint8List(width*height*3);
for (int i=0;i<width*height;i++) {
  int val = (signed)?data[i].abs():data[i];
  textureData[i*3] = val&0xFF;
  textureData[i*3+1] = val>>8;
  textureData[i*3+2] = (signed && data[i]<0)?255:0;
}
```

And value reconstruction in shader:

```
float tval = texture2D(imageTex, vUv).r/256.0+texture2D(imageTex, vUv).g; 
if (texture2D(imageTex, vUv).b>0.0) tval = -tval
```

But this solution has one big issue, when you zoom in and have GL.LINEAR filtering enabled it draws bad data on high constrast edges in image, because red byte and grean byte are interpolated separately.

Conclusion: Both solutions work, but neither is possible to use with linear texture interpolation. Maybe it is possible to perform manual interpolation in fragment shader.